# Yii2: How to have sum in footer based on previous pages' sum?

Tags: php, gridview, yii2

Please look the picture below.

[image]

As you can see total is **215340** in the summary column. What I want is that in the next page it should start summing those numbers on this number.

Here is a code.

```
 GridView::widget([
    'dataProvider' => $dataProvider,
    //  'filterModel' => $searchModel,
    'columns' => [
      [
        'class' => 'kartik\grid\SerialColumn'],
      //     'id',
      [
        'attribute' => 'customer_id',
        'value' => function ($data) {
          return $data->customerDetail->account_no;
        }
      ],
      [
        'attribute' => 'naration',
        'pageSummary' => 'Total',
      ],
      [
      'attribute' => 'transaction_type',
      'label' => 'Deposits',
      'pageSummary' => true,
      'pageSummaryOptions' => ['id' => 'total_sum'],
      'value' => function ($data) {
        if($data->transaction_type==10)
          return $data->amount;
        else
          return 0;
        }
      ],
      [
      'attribute' => 'transaction_type',
      'label' => 'Withdrawals',
      'pageSummary' => true,
      'value' => function ($data) {
        if($data->transaction_type==11)
          return $data->amount;
        else
          return 0;
        }
      ],
      [
        'class' => 'backend\components\TotalColumn',
        'label' => 'Balance',
        'attribute' =>'amount',
      ],

    ],
    // This line displays sum of the columns.
    'showPageSummary' => true,
  ]);
?>
```

I was thinking about sending this page's sum to the next page using `$_GET` but the problem is when user going to previous pages i.e. from page 3 to 2. Do you any widget or something for this problem?

Comment: Ok. What have you tried so far?

Comment: @AlanMachado nothing. I can't understand what would be possible way to do it.

Comment: That is where **research efforts** lies. Seek into it.

Comment: @AlanMachado I did research on it. Couldn't find something yet.

Comment: We will be waiting, then!

Comment: @ankitraturi I've updated the question with code. Can you look over it?

Comment: Not sure how you got on with this, but the simplest solution would be to do a separate query or queries to get the totals yourself based on page number and results shown per page. You can then include that into your anonymouse 'value' function with ```function($value) use ($previousTotal)```

Answer (score 0):

My idea is using mysql to select sum of all records in the current column and add this value with the total value of the previous page, I need to know offset and limit of the current page for this query, I can get those values from data provider, to achieve this I have to override the function `\yii\grid\Column::renderFooterCellContent()`.

## Extend `\yii\grid\DataColumn` class

```
namespace frontend\components;

use yii\helpers\ArrayHelper;

class DataColumn extends \yii\grid\DataColumn
{
    protected function renderFooterCellContent()
    {
        if ($this->footer instanceof \Closure) {
            return call_user_func($this->footer, ArrayHelper::getValue($this, 'grid.dataProvider.pagination'));
        } else {
            return parent::renderFooterCellContent();
        }
    }
}
```

## Your view file

```
use frontend\models\Client;
use yii\db\Expression;
use yii\db\Query;
use yii\grid\GridView;
use yii\data\Pagination;
use frontend\components\DataColumn;

echo GridView::widget([
    'dataProvider' => $dataProvider,
    'dataColumnClass' => DataColumn::className(),
    'showFooter' => true,
    'columns' => [
        //['class' => 'yii\grid\SerialColumn'],
        'id',
        [
            'attribute' => 'num_users',
            'footer' => function ($pagination) {
                if ($pagination instanceof Pagination) {
                    $offset = $pagination->offset;
                    $limit = $pagination->limit;

                    $cquery = (new Query())
                        ->select(['sub_users' => new Expression('SUM(num_users)')])
                        ->from([
                            'cpage' => (new Query())
                                ->select('num_users')
                                ->offset($offset)
                                ->limit($limit)
                                ->from(Client::tableName())
                        ]);

                    //negative offset is illegal
                    if ($offset > 0) {
                        $pquery = (new Query())
                            ->select(['sub_users' => new Expression('SUM(num_users)')])
                            ->from([
                                'ppage' => (new Query())
                                    ->select('num_users')
                                    ->offset(0)
                                    ->limit($offset)
                                    ->from(Client::tableName())
                            ]);
                        $cquery->union($pquery, true);
                    }

                    return (new Query())->from(['subt' => $cquery])->sum('sub_users');
                }
            }
        ],
    ]
]);
```

## Raw SQL query

```
SELECT SUM(sub_sum_users) FROM (
    SELECT SUM(num_users) as sub_sum_users FROM (
        SELECT num_users FROM `clients` LIMIT 20 OFFSET 120
    ) cpage
    UNION ALL
    SELECT SUM(num_users) as sub_sum_users FROM (
        SELECT num_users FROM `clients` LIMIT 20 OFFSET 100
    ) ppage
) sublt
```

### Note:

You could consider to use ActiveRecord, my girdview has a lot of join queries so it's very heavy for me

```
$offset = $pagination->offset;
$limit = $pagination->limit;
$cquery = Client::find()
    ->select(['sub_users' => new Expression('SUM(num_users)')])
    ->from([
        'cpage' => Client::find()->select('num_users')->offset($offset)->limit($limit)
    ]);

//negative offset is illegal
if ($offset > 0) {
    $pquery = $cquery = Client::find()
        ->select(['sub_users' => new Expression('SUM(num_users)')])
        ->from([
            'ppage' => Client::find()->select('num_users')->offset(0)->limit($offset)
        ]);
    $cquery->union($pquery, true);
}

return (new Query())->from(['subt' => $cquery])->sum('sub_users');
```